# SendGrid with Node.js and express

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use Sendgrid in Node.js and I'm all new with them.

I used express to build a website and use `app.post` to get the email address from the form on the website. I do can get the email address but when it supposed to send to email, I received the `ResponseError: Bad Request` error.

I tried to re-write in different ways but I get the same problem.

This is what I wrote in Node (I hid the apikey and my eamil address), `server.js`:

```
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail")
sgMail.setApiKey("SG....................SsSwXtdjRE")

const app = express()
app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
)

app.listen(3000, function(err) {
    if(err) console.error(err);
    console.log("successfully connected")
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '\\index.html')
})


app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    var email = String(req.body.email)
    console.log(email)

    const msg = {
        to: email,
        from: "...@...com",
        text: "hello world"
    }    
    console.log(msg)
    
    sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
        console.log("Email sent successfully")
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Failed")
        console.error(error)
    })
})
```

The code in html is just a form with POST method and some inputs.

This is the error in the terminal:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mze08.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see there is `body` with errors, so you can try to `console.log(error.response.body)` to check what errors you have. But checking your code I assume it could be:

1. Missing "subject" field.
2. Invalid `from` email. As I remember, it has to match your Sendgrid account or domain you specified there.

Comment: Thanks so much! I miss the 'subject' field because I thought it's not mandatory